# RangetoHTML no longer working

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the macro I get

> Compile Error: Wrong number of arguements or invalid property assignment

the `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)` is highlighted yellow and format in the `TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"` line is highlighted gray

```
Sub GenerateEmail()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    MsgBox "This will generate an email, please check Outlook"

    Set rng = Sheets("ERC NPA").Range("B2:H23").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("G13") & " : Payment Request"
        .HTMLBody = "Please find below payment request form" & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not getting any compile errors for your code. What version of Excel are you using? One issue I can see is that the `RangetoHTML` function does not specify a return type (but it defaults to `Variant`, so it's not giving an error).

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code actually. It just run fine with a test sheet.

Comment: It is really frustrating as it used to work fine and in the last week it has stopped working. do you think it could be a version of excel thing?  There must be an answer

Comment: You've almost certainly created a function or other routine called `Format`. Put the cursor on the word `Format` and press Shift+f2

Comment: perhaps one of your Tools -> References is unchecked?

Comment: Rory nailed it on the head. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testFunction()
'   Try testing the function like this to pinpoint the problem
'   It works fine for me on Excel 2013
'   Cool function, btw
Dim rng As Range
Dim someString As String

    Set rng = Sheets("ERC NPA").Range("B2:H23").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    someString = RangetoHTML(rng)
    Debug.Print someString

Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of Macro Coding named "Format" to something else. In the "Function" it is calling that macro however it is meant for temp file.