# Attach temporary excel file and include signature to outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a workbook with three worksheets named Presentation, Calculation, and Support. In the Calculation tab, I've placed a macro button to run the following code. My objective is to compose an Outlook email, attaching the current workbook, but only displaying the Presentation worksheet with all its cells hardcoded. Additionally, I want to showcase the dynamic chart in the Presentation worksheet which starts from cell B6.

Now, the code below aims to create a temporary file and delete every worksheet except Presentation. Subsequently, it attempts to attach this temporary file to the Outlook email. Furthermore, I'm trying to copy the dynamic chart from the Presentation tab to the bottom of the email, just before my Outlook signature. The code is performing all other tasks correctly except for these three things: attaching the file, pasting the dynamic chart accurately, and placing my Outlook signature.

```
Sub SendEmailWithPresentationAndSignature()
    Dim cName As String
    Dim cEmail As String
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartRange As Range
    Dim tempWb As Workbook
    Dim tempFilePath As String
    
    ' Prompt user for name and email
    cName = InputBox("Enter Name:")
    cEmail = InputBox("Enter Email:")
    
    ' Check if the user pressed Cancel
    If cName = "" Or cEmail = "" Then
        MsgBox "Operation canceled. Name and Email are required.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set reference to the Presentation worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Presentation")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the Presentation worksheet exists
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet 'Presentation' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the range for the cells (adjust the range based on your data location)
    Set chartRange = ws.Range("B6", ws.Cells(7, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    ' Create a temporary workbook
    Set tempWb = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Copy only the "Presentation" sheet to the temporary workbook
    ws.Copy Before:=tempWb.Sheets(1)
    tempWb.Sheets(2).Delete ' Delete the default sheet created with the temporary workbook
    
    ' Get the temporary file path
    tempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "TempPresentationWorkbook.xlsx"
    
    ' Save the temporary workbook
    tempWb.SaveAs tempFilePath, FileFormat:=51 ' FileFormat 51 is for xlsx format
    tempWb.Close False ' Close the temporary workbook without saving changes
    
    ' Create Outlook application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set outlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If Outlook is not running, create a new instance
    If outlookApp Is Nothing Then
        Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    
    ' Create a new mail item
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Set the email properties
    With outlookMail
        .To = cEmail
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & cName & ",</p>" & _
                    "<p>Please find the attached Presentation worksheet.</p>"
        
        ' Copy the range
        chartRange.Copy
        
        ' Attach the temporary workbook to the email
        .Attachments.Add tempFilePath, 1, 0
        
        ' Paste the range as a picture in the email body
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
  
        ' Include Outlook signature
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & GetOutlookSignature()
        
        ' Display the email (use .Send to send without displaying the email)
        .Display
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary file
    Kill tempFilePath
End Sub

Function GetOutlookSignature() As String
    ' Get Outlook signature using the Outlook.Application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If Outlook is not running, create a new instance
    If outlookApp Is Nothing Then
        Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    
    ' Get the MAPI namespace
    Dim outlookNamespace As Object
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Get the current user's default folder
    Dim outlookFolder As Object
    Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
    
    ' Get the HTMLBody of a dummy mail item to obtain the signature
    Dim dummyMail As Object
    Set dummyMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Return the signature
    GetOutlookSignature = dummyMail.HTMLBody
End Function
```

I am completely lost here on how to resolve these three issues. I appreciate all the help in advanced! I am relatively new to VBA so please let me know if I should explain my code further.

Comment: Do you have to make it a temporary file? I usually just use `.Attachments.Add wb.FullName`. Perhaps try and save it in a "non" temporary place then after it's sent, delete the file. See if that works.

Comment: Regarding the chart. Do you mean table? Ron de Bruin has made a function called RangeToHTML, sadly he has removed the code from his webpage 
but I found a copy of the function here, nor sure if it's complete though https://stackoverflow.com/q/43096639/5159168

Comment: apologies, I do not mean a table. I have dynamic cells that start from cell B6, and can go up to column M depending on the choices I make in the Calculation tab.

Answer (score 1):

Your are asking three questions in one, that is usually not the idea of SO because it makes it hard to answer. It's always better to ask separate questions (so that someone who knows the answer to one of the topics can answer it without taking care about the rest).

Some points:

**(o)** You can simplify the code that saves the worksheet into a new workbook. `Worksheet.Copy` without argument creates a new workbook:

```
Const TmpFilename As String = "TempPresentationWorkbook"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Presentation").Copy       ' This creates a new workbook containing the sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet    ' Set the variable to the new created sheet
Set tempWb = ws.Parent
Dim tempWBFilename As String, tempChartFilename As String
' Get the temporary file path
tempWBFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & TmpFilename & ".xlsx"
tempWb.SaveAs tempWBFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

**(o)** I see no reason not to use early binding. Just add a reference to `Microsoft Outlook Object library` (Tools->References).

**(o)** There will always be only one instance of Outlook running on your computer, so it's not necessary to check if it is already running. Just use

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
```

If it is already running, `outlookApp` will point to that instance, else it will be started first.
BTW: No need to execute the "Cleanup" part of your code.

---

Now to your problems:
**(o)** You attach the file successfully, however, it is not displayed. The reason is that you pass `0` as position to the `Attachment.Add` command. This will hide the attachment. Simply change the value to `1`.

```
.Attachments.Add tempWBFilename, 1, 1
```

**(o)** The (default) signature can be read when you issue the `.Display` command immediately after creating the mail item. See [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook)

```
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
' Set the email properties
With outlookMail
    .Display
    Dim signature As String
    signature = .HTMLBody
```

**(o)** I don't know if it is possible to Paste something to the `HTML` content as you try to do. I suggest to save the chart also as (temporary) file as described here: [Export chart as image - with click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939087/export-chart-as-image-with-click-of-a-button), add it as hidden attachment and embed it into the text as described here: [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba)

```
' Save the chart
tempChartFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & TmpFilename & ".jpg"
' Save the temporary workbook and the chart
Dim co As ChartObject
Set co = ws.ChartObjects(1)
co.Chart.Export tempChartFilename, "JPG"
(...)

.Attachments.Add tempChartFilename, 1, 0
.HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & cName & ",</p>" _
              & "<p>Please find the attached Presentation worksheet.</p>" _
              & "<img src=""cid:" & TmpFilename & ".jpg"">"
              & "<p/>" & signature
```

---

So your complete code could look like (I leave out the part where you ask for receiver name and address)

```
Const TmpFilename As String = "TempPresentationWorkbook"

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tempWb As Workbook

' Create a copy of the Presentation sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Presentation").Copy  ' This creates a new workbook containing the sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet    ' Set the variable to the new created sheet
Set tempWb = ws.Parent
Dim tempWBFilename As String, tempChartFilename As String
' Get the temporary file path
tempWBFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & TmpFilename & ".xlsx"
tempWb.SaveAs tempWBFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

' Save the Chart
tempChartFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & TmpFilename & ".jpg"
Dim co As ChartObject
Set co = ws.ChartObjects(1)    
co.Chart.Export tempChartFilename, "JPG"

' Open Outlook and create a new Mail item
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

' Set the email properties
With outlookMail
    .Display
    Dim signature As String
    signature = .HTMLBody

    .To = cEmail
    .Subject = "Subject"       
    .Attachments.Add tempWBFilename, 1, 0
    .Attachments.Add tempChartFilename, 1, 2
    
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & cName & ",</p>" _
              & "<p>Please find the attached Presentation worksheet.</p>" _
              & "<img src=""cid:" & TmpFilename & ".jpg"">" _
              & "<p/>" & signature
    ' .Send
End With

' Delete the temporary files
tempWb.Close False ' Close the temporary workbook without saving changes
Kill tempWBFilename
Kill tempChartFilename
```

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough reply! I noticed that the code `Set co = ws.ChartObjects(1)` doesn't work properly for me. This is because I misspoke here. I don't have a visual chart starting in B6, instead I have dynamic formulas referring to the Calculation (apologies that I called it a chart)